# How to export data table with proper formatting and write text in Excel using C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Tags: c#, datatable, formatting, export-to-excel

I'm using this function to export a data table into excel.

```
  protected void ExportExcel(System.Data.DataTable dt) 
    { 
         if (dt == null||dt.Rows.Count==0) return; 
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = 
new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); 

 if (xlApp == null) 
 { 
     return; 
 } 
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo CurrentCI = 
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; 
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"); 
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks workbooks = xlApp.Workbooks; 
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = 
 workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet); 
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = 
(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1]; 
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range; 
 long totalCount = dt.Rows.Count; 
 long rowRead = 0; 
 float percent = 0; 
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) 
 { 
     worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName; 
     range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1]; 
     range.Interior.ColorIndex = 15; 
     range.Font.Bold = true; 

 } 

 for (int r = 0; r < dt.Rows.Count; r++) 
 { 
     for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) 
     { 
         worksheet.Cells[r + 2, i + 1] = dt.Rows[r][i].ToString(); 
     } 
     rowRead++; 
     percent = ((float)(100 * rowRead)) / totalCount; 
 }

 xlApp.Visible = true;
}
```

[image: RESULT iMAGE]

As you can see in the resulting excel image, the columns are not properly formatted i.e., the column sizes do not adapt to the databound items. How will I make the excel cells auto-adjust according to the data table?

And I also would like to add some text, maybe a header, for say maybe "System.DateTime.Now" or "data table name". How do i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to format the columns like so:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range columns = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns;
columns.AutoFit();
```

You can insert a new row and place the current date as the title like so:

```
worksheet.Rows[1].Insert();
Excel.Range newRow = worksheet.Rows[1];
Excel.Range newCell = newRow.Cells[1];
newCell.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Also add this to your using statements so you don't need to use the fully qualified name every time you use an Excel object:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Also, I have tidied up your method, by adding a few using statements to reduce clutter, removing some unnecessary casting and an unnesscessary check for null on the application object, just after it had been assigned:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data;

protected void ExportExcel(DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count == 0) return;

    var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    //Is this used?
    CultureInfo CurrentCI = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    Excel.Workbooks workbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;

    Excel.Range range

    Excel.Workbook workbook = workbooks.Add();
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];

    long totalCount = dt.Rows.Count;
    long rowRead = 0;
    float percent = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;

        range = worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1];
        range.Interior.ColorIndex = 15;
        range.Font.Bold = true;
    }

    for (var r = 0; r < dt.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[r + 2, i + 1] = dt.Rows[r][i].ToString();
        }

        rowRead++;

        //is this used?
        percent = ((float)(100 * rowRead)) / totalCount;
    }    

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range columns = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns;
    columns.AutoFit();

    worksheet.Rows[1].Insert();
    Excel.Range newRow = worksheet.Rows[1];
    Excel.Range newCell = newRow.Cells[1];
    newCell.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    xlApp.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, had a few errors. on line " entireSheet.AutoFit(); " - COMexception was unhandled - AutoFit method of Range class failed. On  line " Excel.Range newRow = worksheet.Rows.Insert();" - COMexception was unhandled  - "To prevent possible loss of data, Excel cannot shift nonblank cells off of the worksheet.  Select another location in which to insert new cells, or delete data from the end of your worksheet. "

Comment: Can I ask what versions of the interop libraries you are using?  I am getting errors on line: worksheet.Rows[1].Insert(); Error is No overload for method 'this' takes '1' arguments and sure enough, docs say you need two arguments (column and row).  My library is: 12.0.0.0